# how do i access a sheet name in gsp spreadsheet.worksheets()

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets-api

I have google spreadsheet with different tabs.  These hold quarterly metrics, e.g. 1Q14, 2Q14, etc.

I want to read these data and convert it to a Pandas DataFrame.

I managed to write code to open the spreadsheet with GSP.open 
[see first code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh23d.png)

Then I want to iterate over all sheets and extract their names from the list I obtain with:
sheets = spreadsheet.worksheets()
[list of sheets returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m05ZN.png)

I want to get the first part, the name, not the id.  I know I can obtain the full first entry in the list with sheet[0], but now, how do I get the name only, without the id?

How do I access the sheet name in that object that is returned?  I can't find it - appreciate your help.  Thank you, Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access the property `title` of the sheet, like this:

```py
sheets = spreadsheet.worksheets()
for sheet in sheets:
  sheet.title
```

#### Reference:

- [gspread: API Reference](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)

Comment: Thank you,  should have thought of that myself...:-)

Comment: @MarcBenkert You're welcome. Also, remember that you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) answers that you consider helpful. This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.

Comment: Thank you--this answered my question as well. To save all titles to a list, you can use sheet_titles = [worksheet.title for worksheet in spreadsheet.worksheets()] .